# Magento 1.9 - how to create an new observer on the event "customer_register_success" from the top

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, address

I'm quite newbie in magento. I'm trying to create observer on the event "customer_register_success". I follow the tutorial about how to compose the files in local module. **But it didn't work.**

When customer register on our website, customer should select the country where they live and it is saved as billing address. The goal i want to meet is that if customer live in United State, their group is standard group(just default group). If not, like live in Jamaica, Spain, they are assigned to international group automatically.

I know that GROUP exist because of tax class tho. but i must make it.

our website's customer group information is,
[image]

***I'm willing to set the groupid based on their country name,id.*** 
As you see the following,

> 1)Directory

[image]

> 2)app/etc/modules/Kbethos_CustomerGrouped.xml

First of all, I added a module configuration file to the **app/etc/modules** directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
    <Kbethos_CustomerGrouped>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Kbethos_CustomerGrouped>
    </modules>
</config>
```

> 3) app/code/local/Kbethos/CustomerGrouped/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Kbethos_CustomerGrouped>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Kbethos_CustomerGrouped>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <customergrouped>
                <class>Kbethos_CustomerGrouped_Helper</class>
            </customergrouped>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <kbethos_customergrouped>
                <class>Kbethos_CustomerGrouped_Model</class>
            </kbethos_customergrouped>
        </models>
        <events>
            <customer_register_success>
                <observers>
                    <kbethos_customergrouped>
                        <class>kbethos_customergrouped/observer</class>
                        <method>customerRegisterSuccess</method>
                    </kbethos_customergrouped>
                </observers>
            </customer_register_success>
    </events>
    </global> 
</config>
```

> 4)app/code/local/Kbethos/CustomerGrouped/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
  class Kbethos_CustomerGrouped_Model_Observer {
  public function customerRegisterSuccess(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

 $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $customer = $event->getCustomer();
    $billingAddress = $customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress();

    if ($billingAddress) {
        $countryId = $billingAddress->getCountryId();
        switch ($countryId) {
            case 'US':
                $customer->setData('group_id', 1);
                $customer->save();
                break;
            default:
                $customer->setData('group_id', 27);
                $customer->save();
        }
    }

}
}


?>
```

5) /wh-clone/app/code/local/Kbethos/CustomerGrouped/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php 

class Kbethos_CustomerGrouped_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

What sould i do more? please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Your code is correct. Check if your module is enabled, also put a log entry on your observer method to check if it is being called

Comment: @JaiminSutariya As i mention before, I'm too newbie on Magento. Could you let me know how to log this file by using mage::log or die (). I just heard about those methods but i don't get it how to log it. Where can i put the log command?

Comment: @JaiminSutariya i put Mage::log('customergroup', null, 'system.log', true);  in Observer.php and after looking at the log file, it is written to "2017-02-17T22:00:23+00:00 DEBUG (7): customergroup"  like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are getting message in log then your observer is being called. There is no issue there.
So, now the issue is related to get billing information of the customer. Try loading customer before you get customer billing address.

```
class Kbethos_CustomerGrouped_Model_Observer {
    public function customerRegisterSuccess(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $customer = $event->getCustomer();
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer->getId());
        $billingAddress = $customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress();
        if ($billingAddress) {
            $countryId = $billingAddress->getCountryId();
            switch ($countryId) {
                case 'US':
                    $customer->setData('group_id', 1);
                    $customer->save();
                    break;
                default:
                    $customer->setData('group_id', 27);
                    $customer->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can also use

```
$billingAddress = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
```

Comment: When i add your code,

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in app/code/local/Kbethos/CustomerGrouped/Model/Observer.php on line 10

Comment: This error comes out

Comment: Try with updated code

Comment: Oh my gooooooood! It works. Could you let me know how to work it? is it okay to overwrite the variable name? I'm really seeking the method to bind the customer id tho! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @JaiminSutariya I am using sales_order_place_after, how to know what are the details enclosed like name, price, qty_ordered, etc

Comment: @zus, if you are using `sales_order_pace_after` then you can easily get complete order by `$event->getOrder()` and then you can get any details from the order.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya Shall i view what are all details available, like getSku(), getName(), i mean how can i view all list?

Comment: @zus, you will require to use `$order->getAllItems()` in a froeach loop to get each item object and then you can get product details by `$item->getSku()`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try to register even as shown below:

```
<events>
        <customer_register_success>
            <observers>
                <customergrouped>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Kbethos_CustomerGrouped_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>customerRegisterSuccess</method>
                </customergrouped>
            </observers>
        </customer_register_success>
</events>
```

Comment: I am using sales_order_place_after, how to know what are the details enclosed like name, price, qty_ordered, etc @Prasanta Hatui