# Event "customer_register_success" not working in Magento1.9.2.4

Tags: customer, event-observer, register, magento1.9.2.4

Here  is the code-

**app/etc/modules/Ds_Customerlog.xml -**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Ds_Customerlog>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Ds_Customerlog>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Ds/Customerlog/etc/config.xml -**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Ds_Customerlog>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Ds_Customerlog>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <customerlog>
        <class>Ds_Customerlog_Helper</class>
      </customerlog>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <ds_customerlog>
        <class>Ds_Customerlog_Model</class>
    </ds_customerlog>
    </models>
    <events>
      <customer_register_success> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
          <observers>
            <customer_register_success_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
              <class>Ds_Customerlog_Model_Observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
              <method>observer</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            </customer_register_success_handler>
          </observers>
        </customer_register_success>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Ds/Customerlog/Model/Observer.php** -

```
<?php
class Ds_Customerlog_Model_Observer
{

    public function observer(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        die("sfs");
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        Mage::log($customer->getFirstname(), null, 'customer.log'); 
    }

}
```

Here `die("sfs")` not being executed on customer registration on both frontend and backend.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check with below url - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160563/magento-1-9-how-to-create-an-new-observer-on-the-event-customer-register-succ

Comment: @shashank, I just check your code in 1.9.3.8 and it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

For the frontend, you can use the below link.

http://easyndfaster.com/blog/post/magento-1-customer-after-save-event-triggered-front-end-side/

For the backend, you can use the below link.

http://easyndfaster.com/blog/post/magento-1-customer-after-save-event-triggered-admin-side/